# What is the analog of the PDF and CDF for the likelihood function?

Tags: probability, density-function, likelihood, cumulative-distribution-function, integral

In probability, we can find the cdf using the pdf and vise-versa.
Integrating pdf yields the cdf.

Does integrating the likelihood function yield any important thing?

In statistics, $\mathcal{L} (M\mid X )= P(X \mid M) $.

If, cdf is to pdf, then likelihood is to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likelihood integration (with respect to $M$) doesn't make sense because it doesn't even integrate/sum to $1$ if we iterate over all possible $M$'s. However, integration/sum of likelihood multiplied with prior makes sense because the integral is equal to the *evidence*.

With respect to $x$, it's still a density/PMF and its integral is a CDF.